# How to rename columns in an SQL-server database

Tags: sql-server, database-design, stored-procedures, rename

My employer has the habit of giving customer specific tables a name, starting with the name of the customer. This makes it difficult to call the `sp_rename` stored procedure for renaming column names, as you can see:

```sql
/*Version 1:*/
sp_rename 'Customer.FinishedProduct.ShortDescr', 'ShortDescription', 'COLUMN';
sp_rename 'Customer.LogTrackAndTrace.StorePreceddure', 'StoredProcedure', 'COLUMN';
/*Version 2:*/
sp_rename '[Customer.FinishedProduct].[ShortDescr]', '[ShortDescription]', 'COLUMN';
sp_rename '[Customer.LogTrackAndTrace].[StorePreceddure]', '[StoredProcedure]', 'COLUMN';
```

Both versions don't work.

Do you know how this can be written? (The name of a table is 'Customer.FinishedProduct'.)

Comment: What is the error message? Could you [edit] your question and add the details as text?

Comment: Add the create table DDL to your question for clarity. If `Customer` is the table schema name rather than part of the table name itself, I would expect the version 1 scripts to work. If `Customer.` is part of the table name and the table is in your default schema (e.g. `dbo`, version 2 scripts should work.

Comment: Just to reinforce what John said, "don't work" is absolutely unhelpful for anyone who might try to help you.  In what way did it not work?  Imagine that someone came to you with this problem.  What additional information would you need them to share?

Comment: You could also have a dot in a table name which is not ASCII 46. eg select nchar(46), nchar(183), nchar(65106), nchar(65294)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your table (or schema?) has the dot/period character - `.` in the name?

The following example shows how you can rename a column when the object names (both schema and object in this case) have that character in them.

```
CREATE DATABASE Test
GO

USE Test
GO

CREATE SCHEMA [a.b]
GO

CREATE TABLE [a.b].[c.d]
(
    e INT
)

GO

sp_rename '[a.b].[c.d].[e]', 'New', 'COLUMN';
```

`SELECT * FROM [a.b].[c.d]`

[image]

Comment: The weird thing is that it works if I only launch one command (from the ones with the square brackets), but when I try to launch both it fails.